A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame while using loc
I am aware that this is a common issue, but I am confused why I am getting it here:
 train_df.loc[:,'decision'] = np.where(train_probs[:,1]>cutoff, 1, 0)

I am doing exactly what the warning says:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

And yet, it's still complaining, any ideas?

Run train_df = train_df.copy() prior to your line of code. If this solves the issue, this means that the cause for your warning is pre-existing (and not reproducible with your example).
